# In webhosting Where to store my code and Image files and how to access them?

Tags: javascript, java, web-hosting

I have a verified domain name on GoDaddy.com and I have a cPanel account. I've included all of my code files there. I have to store my image files there and also I have to retrieve them in both my java and javascript files.

In my eclipse project I've accessed my image files from local disk and when I store them here, how will I access them from the server? Do I need to change my code for that?? And first of all where to store them?? In database or any file folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, search for the option "File Manager" in your cPanel. Inside File Manager you can find a `htdocs` folder. If you can see an another folder as the name of your website, like `example.com`, open that one folder! Surely there you can find `htdocs`. Simply create a folder inside it! e.g. `images`. And store your images there.

For example, you've stored a image such as "Nature.jpeg" in `images` folder. To access this file, you have to visit this URL formation:- `https://yourwebsite/images/Nature.jpeg`

And if you don't create a `images` folder & store it there (inside `htdocs`), the file will be placed in this format:- `https://yourwebsite/Nature.jpeg`.

Hope it helps.